# Bracket Algebra, Straightening Algorithm

Tags: matlab, algorithms, c++, computational-geometry, maple

My apologies if the question is simple. I need to write a code for straightening algorithm. Which includes defining bracket algebra. I tried to write it in CoCoA-5, but it wasn't possible because CoCoA-5 does not accept brackets like [1,4,6,8] as ring's indeterminates. I did some Googleing and got more confused.
Can anyone introduce a Computer Algebra System which is capable of defining bracket algebra, computing G-Basis, defining ideals and other abilities which are required in Lie algebra and commutative algebra?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert in Lie algebras, but the first place I would look is Sage.